# Solving a complex recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence, master-theorem

How to solve the below recurrence relation?

```
T(n) = 2T(root(n)) + logn/loglogn if n > 4
T(n) = 1 if n <= 4
```

Preferably by master theorem otherwise by any method.
I know Master Theorem fails,But is there any extension for these type of problems?
Can you guide me any stuff for solving complex relation like above?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Also, this is probably off topic as it's not a specific programming problem.

Comment: So according to you where should I ask this question

Comment: [cs.se] might be more on topic. But I strongly doubt they will be very welcoming, with the question as it currently stands, as per the above reasons (questions should demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved).

Comment: This is a simple 1-dimensional recursion, what's stopping you from expanding the expression 2-3 times and trying to spot the regularity? Convert the root to a power, that might tickle your memory about log rules

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

if n = 2^m and T(2^m) = s(m) then

logn = m , loglogn = logm ;

s(m) = 2*s(m/2) + m/logm ;

now solving the above equation is our problem 
now you can not use the master theorem for solving this , so you have to use other methods like expanding this equation by writing s(m/2) and s(m/4) and then you might solve this problem , and after doing that you change your parameters to n again .

Answer (score 0):

According to me

if n = 2^m and T(2^m) = s(m) then

logn = m , loglogn = logm ;

s(m) = 2*s(m/2) + m/logm ;

[image: T(n)=2T(sqrt(n))+ logn/loglogn]